# fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

Tags: git

I'm a Windows 10 user, using gitbash as a command prompt.

After I changed the branch to `master`, suddenly I'm struck with this error message.

```
REDMOND+ahkim@ahkim-1211 MINGW64 /c/git/src/SI_leadscore/SalesIntelligence/LeadScore/Model (aerin/LeadOptimizerModel)
$ git checkout master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

REDMOND+ahkim@ahkim-1211 MINGW64 /c/git/src/SI_leadscore/SalesIntelligence/LeadScore/Model
$ git checkout LeadOptimizerModel
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

REDMOND+ahkim@ahkim-1211 MINGW64 /c/git/src/SI_leadscore/SalesIntelligence/LeadScore/Model
$ git branch
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

REDMOND+ahkim@ahkim-1211 MINGW64 /c/git/src/SI_leadscore/SalesIntelligence/LeadScore/Model
$ git status
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

git checkout, git branch, git status, etc.
None of them works.

Comment: Are you in the root directory of your git repository? If not, maybe the directory you're in doesn't exist on the master branch. Try "cd .." a few times until you're at the repository root.

Comment: Yes Exactly. master branch doesn't have the directory I'm in. :-0

Comment: Personally, I always use Git from the directory which has the `.git` directory in it(usually the main directory of a project). That way, the directory I'm in always exists.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your current directory doesn't exist on the master branch. It was deleted when you checked it out. `cd ..` a few times until you find a directory that exists.

Comment: holy moly never was there such a simple solution to such a brown trousers moment

Comment: Oh my. This was it. I was running the command from a directory that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: type pwd. it will show you , your current dir

Comment: I still don't understand why, but `cd ..`and then `cd` back into the directory I was in (should have been in), did the job.

Answer (score 6):

I got this message when trying to execute git commands in Crosh on a Chromebook.

> fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

The local files were on a removable drive (an SDXC card in this case).  I fixed it by changing directory up and back into the repo's main directory:

```
$ cd ..
$ cd (my repo's directory)
```

And presto, git was working again.  I've used this set up a lot, I have no idea what happened, other than maybe Chrome OS got confused and didn't know what was going on.  But

```
$ pwd
```

worked fine before I fixed the issue, while the error was happening.

Answer (score 3):

That error won't happen again after <del>Git 2.35 (Q1 2022)</del>:
Actually, **after Git 2.35.1** (Jan. 29th 2022, see last section of this answer)

No more "`fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory`"

Many `git` commands that deal with working tree files tried to remove a directory that becomes empty (i.e.
"[`git switch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/da81d473fcfa67dfbcf0504d2b5225885e51e532/Documentation/git-switch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))</sup> from a branch that has the directory to another branch that does not would attempt remove all files in the directory and the directory itself).
This drops users into an unfamiliar situation if the command was run in a subdirectory that becomes subject to removal due to the command.

The commands have been taught to keep an empty directory if it is the directory they were started in to avoid surprising users.

See [commit 324b170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/324b170b88475811cb0506a30b4710ffc89ae936), [commit 580a5d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/580a5d7f75fc7b6c4c369ef429742d9d417acddd), [commit 63bbe8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63bbe8beb78ee8af5a7faeee4be747a82d8e2dc7), [commit 0fce211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fce211cccd0dce848d217cd4e2037214d7be1dd), [commit bc3ae46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc3ae46b420f58dfe2bfd87714dca096a043d554), [commit c65744e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c65744e7d7f512f3666da5964f0ace90325dd94a), [commit 00fcce2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00fcce285db3db48f85730a183421fdb488c14cc), [commit 0b0ee33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b0ee3388cf080c4200c235ee699bd95c960c167), [commit b817e54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b817e545338cdb737b3deebf4917afb4a18ede57), [commit e6f8861](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6f8861bd43636b27651150e6a3caa0a937fb418), [commit 8a0d52d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0d52dfd870af50b9c28baf66347f5eaaf14e6e) (09 Dec 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit da81d47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da81d473fcfa67dfbcf0504d2b5225885e51e532), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63bbe8beb78ee8af5a7faeee4be747a82d8e2dc7): avoid incidentally removing the `original_cwd` in `remove_path()`
>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Modern git often tries to avoid leaving empty directories around when removing files.
> Originally, it did not bother.
> This behavior started with [commit 80e21a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80e21a9ed809d98788ff6fb705d911bee37d460b) ("`merge-recursive`::removeFile: remove empty directories", 2005-11-19, Git v0.99.9k -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93dcab2937624ebb97f91807576cddb242a55a46)), stating the reason simply as:
>
> ```
> When the last file in a directory is removed as the result of a
> merge, try to rmdir the now-empty directory.
> ```
>
> This was reimplemented in C and renamed to `remove_path()` in [commit e1b3a2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1b3a2cad79a8138d18593c6eb3c46906ad2ee42) ("Build-in merge-recursive", 2008-02-07, Git v1.5.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a4d707a6d914fcea302e299fc18892d9e42c767)), but was still internal to merge-recursive.
>
> This trend towards removing leading empty directories continued with [commit d9b814c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b814cc97f16daac06566a5340121c446136d22) (Add builtin , 2006-05-19, Git v1.4.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf78d1a6cb65fe877a8d90b9d4ec95678621ff17)) (Add builtin "[`git rm`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/63bbe8beb78ee8af5a7faeee4be747a82d8e2dc7/Documentation/git-rm.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))</sup> command, 2006-05-19), which stated the reasoning as:
>
> > The other question is what to do with leading directories.
> > The old "`git rm`" script didn't do anything, which is somewhat inconsistent.
> > This one will actually clean up directories that have become empty
> > as a result of removing the last file, but maybe we want to have a
> > flag to decide the behaviour?
>
> `remove_path()` in [`dir.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/63bbe8beb78ee8af5a7faeee4be747a82d8e2dc7/dir.c) was added in [4a92d1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a92d1bfb784b09641180d164e7d719080165dc4) ("Add `remove_path`: a function to remove as much as possible of a path", 2008-09-27, Git v1.6.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9800c0df412869c7949935b61581b9361fc49bd1)), because it was noted that we had two separate implementations of the same idea AND both were buggy.
> It described the purpose of the function as
>
> > a function to remove as much as possible of a path
>
> Why remove as much as possible?  Well, at the time we probably would have said something like:
>
> - removing leading directories makes things feel tidy
> - removing leading directories doesn't hurt anything so long as they had no files in them.
>
> But I don't believe those reasons hold when the empty directory happens to be the current working directory we inherited from our parent process.
> Leaving the parent process in a deleted directory can cause user confusion when subsequent processes fail: any git command, for example, will immediately fail with
>
> ```
> fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> Other commands may similarly get confused.
>
> **Modify `remove_path()` so that the empty leading directories it also deletes does not include the current working directory we inherited from our parent process**.

---

With Git 2.35.1 (Jan. 29th, 2022), fix a regression in 2.35 that broke the use of "`rebase`" and "`stash`" in a secondary worktree.

See [commit ff5b791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff5b7913f0af62c26682b0376d0aa2d7f5d74b2e) (26 Jan 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b23dac9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b23dac905bde28da47543484320db16312c87551), 26 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer, stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff5b7913f0af62c26682b0376d0aa2d7f5d74b2e): fix running from worktree subdir
>
> <sup>Test-case-by: Glen Choo</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> In commits [bc3ae46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc3ae46b420f58dfe2bfd87714dca096a043d554) (`rebase`: do not attempt to remove startup_info->original_cwd, 2021-12-09, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da81d473fcfa67dfbcf0504d2b5225885e51e532) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83ba647f7c61cf945690d6a0bd8c172a6498dc8)) ("rebase: do not attempt to remove `startup_info->original_cwd",` 2021-12-09) and [0fce211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fce211cccd0dce848d217cd4e2037214d7be1dd) (`stash`: do not attempt to remove startup_info->original_cwd, 2021-12-09, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da81d473fcfa67dfbcf0504d2b5225885e51e532) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83ba647f7c61cf945690d6a0bd8c172a6498dc8)) ("stash: do not attempt to remove `startup_info->original_cwd",` 2021-12-09), we wanted to allow the subprocess to know which directory the parent process was running from, so that the subprocess could protect it.
> However...
>
> When run from a non-main worktree, `setup_git_directory()` will note that the discovered git directory (/PATH/TO/.git/worktree/non-main-worktree) does not match `DEFAULT_GIT_DIR_ENVIRONMENT` (see `setup_discovered_git_dir()`), and decide to set `GIT_DIR` in the environment.
> This matters because...
>
> Whenever git is run with the `GIT_DIR` environment variable set, and `GIT_WORK_TREE` not set, it presumes that '.' is the working tree.
> So...
>
> This combination results in the subcommand being very confused about the working tree.
> Fix it by also setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable along with setting `cmd.dir`.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), disable the "do not remove the directory the user started Git in" logic when Git cannot tell where that directory is.
Earlier we refused to run in such a case.

See [commit c37c6dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c37c6dc6a79a1ca7b9d4fa4efd788d8f5ec6369a) (24 May 2022) by [Kevin Locke (`kevinoid`)](https://github.com/kevinoid).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 37d4ae5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37d4ae58efcc9f716435f327c39d5552aedb4b7c), 03 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`setup`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c37c6dc6a79a1ca7b9d4fa4efd788d8f5ec6369a): don't die if `realpath(3)` fails on `getcwd(3)`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kevin Locke</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Prior to Git 2.35.0, git could be run from an inaccessible working directory so long as the git repository specified by options and/or environment variables was accessible.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> git init repo
> mkdir -p a/b
> cd a/b
> chmod u-x ..
> git -C "${PWD%/a/b}/repo" status
> ```
>
> If this example seems a bit contrived, consider running with the repository owner as a substitute UID (e.g. with `runuser(1)` or `sudo(8)`) without ensuring the working directory is accessible by that user.
>
> The code added by [e6f8861](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6f8861bd43636b27651150e6a3caa0a937fb418) (`setup`: introduce startup_info->original_cwd, 2021-12-09, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da81d473fcfa67dfbcf0504d2b5225885e51e532) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83ba647f7c61cf945690d6a0bd8c172a6498dc8)) ("setup: introduce `startup_info->original_cwd")` to preserve the working directory attempts to normalize the path using `strbuf_realpath()`.
> If that fails, as in the case above, it is treated as a fatal error.
>
> This commit treats `strbuf_realpath()` errors as non-fatal.
> If an error occurs, `setup_original_cwd()` will continue without applying removal prevention for cwd, resulting in the pre-2.35.0 behavior.
> The risk should be minimal, since git will not operate on a repository with inaccessible ancestors, this behavior is only known to occur when cwd is a descendant of the repository, an ancestor of cwd is inaccessible, and no ancestors of the repository are inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The directory was deleted after checking it out.

Navigate to your directory in which your git file exists then run `git status`