# How does git matches blobs to files across commit trees?

Tags: git, version-control

[Chapter 3.1 of the the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) clearly states that only staged files get to be stored as blobs in the commit tree.

If, like a commit object, a blob gets a hash ID that is unique to its content, how does Git manages to keep track of a correspondence between blobs and files across commits? Hash IDs of same file blobs in different commits can not match since their contents differ.

---

**A simple example:**

Let's suppose I just created an empty repo with no commits. I create a file README.md, stage it and commit it. Git stores a tree object that has a blob identified by the hash of the contents of README.md.

Let's suppose I modify README.md, stage and commit. Git stores a tree object that has a blob identified by a hash of the modified contents of README.md. Naturally, we can expect this second hash to be different from the hash identifying the blob of README.md in the first commit tree.

How would Git answer a request about README.md history?

```
git log README.md
```

My hunch is that it walks over the commit history and compares relevant blobs, but I don't see how can Git know that the blobs correspond to different versions of the same file except in trivial cases.

---

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's actually quite a good question.

The internal storage form of a commit is partly relevant, so let's consider it for a moment.  An individual commit is actually pretty small.  Here is one from the Git repository for Git, namely commit [`b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a):

```
$ git cat-file -p b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 3f109f9d1abd310a06dc7409176a4380f16aa5f2
parent a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548795295 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548795295 -0800

Fourth batch after 2.20

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(the `sed 's/@/ /'` is just to maybe, possibly, cut down on the amount of email spam that Junio Hamano must get :-) ).  As you can see here, the commit object refers its parent commit object by the other commit's hash ID, `a562a11983...`.  It also refers to a *tree* object by hash ID, and the tree object's hash ID begins with `3f109f9d1a`.  We can look at this tree object using `git cat-file -p` too:

```
$ git cat-file -p 3f109f9d1a | head
100644 blob de1c8b5c77f7566d9e41949e5e397db3cc1b487c    .clang-format
100644 blob 42cdc4bbfb05934bb9c3ed2fe0e0d45212c32d7a    .editorconfig
100644 blob 9fa72ad4503031528e24e7c69f24ca92bcc99914    .gitattributes
040000 tree 7ba15927519648dbc42b15e61739cbf5aeebf48b    .github
100644 blob 0d77ea5894274c43c4b348c8b52b8e665a1a339e    .gitignore
100644 blob cbeebdab7a5e2c6afec338c3534930f569c90f63    .gitmodules
100644 blob 247a3deb7e1418f0fdcfd9719cb7f609775d2804    .mailmap
100644 blob 03c8e4c613015476fffe3f1e071c0c9d6609df0e    .travis.yml
100644 blob 8c85014a0a936892f6832c68e3db646b6f9d2ea2    .tsan-suppressions
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
```

(the tree has quite a lot of data so I've copied only the first ten lines here).

Inside the tree, you see the mode (`100644`), type (`blob`—this is implied by the mode and is also recorded in the internal Git object; it's not actually stored in the tree object), hash ID (`de1c8b5c77f...`), and name (`.clang-format`) of a blob.  You can also see that the `tree` can refer to additional `tree` objects, as is the case for the `.github` sub-tree.

If we take this particular blob object hash ID, we can view that object's contents by hash ID too:

```
$ git cat-file -p de1c8b5c77f | head
# This file is an example configuration for clang-format 5.0.
#
# Note that this style definition should only be understood as a hint
# for writing new code. The rules are still work-in-progress and does
# not yet exactly match the style we have in the existing code.

# Use tabs whenever we need to fill whitespace that spans at least from one tab
# stop to the next one.
#
# These settings are mirrored in .editorconfig.  Keep them in sync.
```

(again I've cut off the copy at 10 lines as the file is quite long).

Just for illustration let's look at the `.github` sub-tree too:

```
$ git cat-file -p 7ba15927519648dbc42b15e61739cbf5aeebf48b
100644 blob 64e605a02b71c51e9f59c429b28961c3152039b9    CONTRIBUTING.md
100644 blob adba13e5baf4603de72341068532e2c7d7d05f75    PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
```

What Git does with these, then, is to read—recursively as needed—the *tree* object from a commit.  Git will read these into a data structure it calls an *index* or *cache*.  (The in-memory version of this is, technically speaking, the *cache* data structure, although Git documentation tends to be a bit loose about which names to use when.)  So the cache built by reading commit `b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a` will say, for instance, that name `.clang-format` has mode `100644` and blob-hash `de1c8b5c77f7566d9e41949e5e397db3cc1b487c`, while name `.github/CONTRIBUTING.md` has mode `100644` and blob-hash `64e605a02b71c51e9f59c429b28961c3152039b9`.

Note that the various name components (`.github` plus `CONTRIBUTING.md`) have, in effect, been joined-up in the in-memory cache.  (In the on-disk format they're compressed via algorithmic trickery.)

#### The in-memory cache that helps Git match up file names

In the end, then, it's the internal (in-memory) cache that holds the <file-name, file-mode, blob-hash> tuples.  If you ask Git to compare commit `b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a` to some other commit, Git reads the other commit into an in-memory cache as well.  That other cache either has an entry named `.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`, or it doesn't.

If both commits have files that have the *same names*, Git assumes—for the purpose of this one comparison that Git is doing right now, and see below—that these are the *same file*.  That's true whether the blob hashes are the same, or not.

The real question we're answering here has to do with *identity*.  The identity of a file, in a version control system, determines whether that file is "the same" file in two different versions (however the version control system itself defines versions).  This relates to the fundamental philosophical question of identity, as outlined in [this Wikipedia article on the thought experiment about the Ship of Thesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus): how do we know that something, or even some*one*, is who or what we think they are?  If you met your cousin Bob when you and he were both very young, and you meet someone again who is named Bob, is he your cousin?  You and he were tiny then; now you're larger and older, with different experiences.  In the real world we seek cues from our environment: is Bob the child of people who are siblings of your parents?  If so, that Bob probably *is* the same cousin Bob you met long ago, even if he (and you) look very different now.

Git, of course, doesn't do any of this.  In most cases the simple fact that both files are named `.github/CONTRIBUTING.md` suffices to identify them as "the same file".  The names are the same, so we're done.

## `git diff` offers extra services

In our everyday development, we sometimes have occasion to *rename* a file.  A file named `a/b.c` might be *renamed* to `d/e.f` or `d/e.c` for some reason.

Suppose we're on commit `a123456` and the file is named `a/b.c`.  Then we move to commit `f789abc`.  That second commit has no `a/b.c` but does have a `d/e.f`.  Git will simply remove `a/b.c` from our index (the on-disk form of the cache) and work-tree, and populate a new `d/e.f` into our index and work-tree, and all is well.

But suppose we ask Git to *compare* `a123456` with `f789abc`.  Git *could* just tell us: *To change `a123456` to `f789abc`, remove `a/b.c` and create a new `d/e.f` with these contents.*  That *is* what `git checkout` did and it suffices.  But what if the contents exactly match?  It's much more *efficient* for Git to tell us: *To change `a123456` to `f789abc`, rename `a/b.c` to `d/e.f`.*  And in fact, with the right options, `git diff` *will* do just that:

```
git diff --find-renames a123456 f789abc
```

How did Git manage this trick?  The answer lies in computing *file identity*.

#### Finding file identity

Suppose that commit *L* (for left-side) has some file (`a/b.c`) that isn't in commit *R* (for right-side).  Suppose further that commit *R* has some file (`d/e.f`) that isn't in commit *L*.  Instead of immediately just telling us: *you should remove the L file and use the R file*, Git can now compare the *contents* of the two files.

Because of the nature of Git object hashes—they are completely deterministic, based on file contents—it's *really easy* for Git to detect that `a/b.c` in *L* is 100% identical to `d/e.f` in *R*.  In this particular case, they will have exactly the same hash ID!  So Git does that: if there's some file that's vanished from *L* and some other file that has appeared in *R*, and Git has been asked to *find* renames, Git checks for hash-ID matches.  If it finds some, it pairs up those files (and takes them out of the queue of unmatched files—this queue, holding files from *L* and *R*, is the "rename detection queue").

Those files with differing names have been identified as the same file.  Little cousin Bob is the same as big cousin Bob after all—except in this case, both of you still need to be little.

So, if this rename-detection hasn't *yet* paired a file in *L* with one in *R*, Git will try harder.  Now it will extract the actual blobs, and compute a sort of "percentage of match".  This uses a complicated little algorithm I won't describe here, but if enough sub-strings within the two files match, Git will declare the files to be 50, 60, 75, or more percent *similar*.

Having found one pair of files in the rename queue that are, say, 72% similar to each other, Git goes on to compare the files to all the other files as well.  If it finds that one of those two is 94% similar to another, that similarity-pairing beats the 72% similarity-pairing.  If not, the 72% similarity is sufficient—it's at least 50%—so Git will pair up those two files and declare that they have the same identity.

In any case, if the match is good enough *and* is the best one among all the unpaired files, that particular match is taken.  Once again, little cousin Bob is the same as big cousin Bob after all.

After running this test on *all* unmatched file pairs, `git diff` takes the matched-up results and calls those files *renamed*.  Again, this only happens if you use `--find-renames` (or `-M`), and you can set the *threshold* to something other than 50% if you like.

#### Breaking incorrect matches

The `git diff` command offers another service.  Note that we started out by *assuming* that if commits *L* and *R* had files with the same *name*, those files were the same *file*, even if the contents differ.  But what if they're not?  What if `file` in *L* got renamed to `bettername` in *R*, *and* someone created a new `file` in *R?*

To handle this, `git diff` offers the `-B` (or "break pairing") option.  With `-B` in effect, files that started out identified by name will have their pairing broken if they are too *dis*-similar.  That is, Git will check whether the two blob hashes match, and if not, Git will compute a similarity index.  If the index falls *below* some threshold, Git will break the pairing and put both files into the rename detection queue, before running the `--find-renames` style rename detector.

As a special twist, Git will *re-pair* broken pairings unless they are so extremely dissimilar that you don't want that to be done.  Hence for `-B` you actually specify *two* similarity thresholds: the first number is when to tentatively break the pairing, and the second is when to permanently break it.

## `git merge` uses `git diff --find-renames`

When you use `git merge` to perform a three-way merge, there are three inputs:

- a merge base commit, which is an ancestor of both tip commits; and
- a left and right commit, `--ours` and `--theirs`.

Git runs *two* `git diff` commands internally.  One compares the base to *L* and the other compares the base to *R*.

Both of these diffs run with `--find-renames` enabled.  If the diff from base to *L* finds a rename, Git knows to use the *changes* shown across that rename.  Likewise, if the diff from base to *R* finds a rename, Git knows to use those changes.  It will combine both sets of changes—and attempt (but usually fail) to combine both renames, if both diffs show a rename.

## `git log --follow` also uses the rename detector

When using `git log --follow`, Git walks the commit history, one commit-pair—child-and-parent—at a time, doing diffs from parent to child.  It turns on a limited form of the rename detection code to see if the one file you're `--follow`-ing was renamed in that commit pair.  If so, as soon as `git log` moves to the parent, it *changes which name it looks for*.  This technique works fairly well, but has some issues at merges (because merge commits have more than one parent).

## Conclusion

*File identity* is what this is all about.  Since Git doesn't know, a priori, that file `a/b.c` in commit *L* is or is not "the same" file as file `d/e.f` in commit *R*, Git can use *rename detection* to decide.  In some cases—such as checking out commit *L* or *R*—this does not matter one bit.  In some cases, such as diffing the two commits, it matters, but only for us as humans trying to understand what happened.  But in a few cases, such as merging, it's *very important*.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, if a file has changed? Well, it actually doesn't matter if the file has changed or not. Each *revision* points to a *tree*, that is, the root directory of the project that the revision represents *at that monent in time*. The tree is a recursive structure that holds the names of more trees (same concept of the root tree) or files. So, you get the name of the tree (a directory) or a file.... and an ID to the *content*. If the object is a file, you get the content, straight... if the object is a tree, well.. you get another tree with a different structure and content... and so on and so on recursively. Now... each *revision* points **also** to its parent revision (or parents, if it's a merge commit). And that revision also holds a tree that of course maps to the content of the project at that moment in time, etc. And voila! no tricks.

So, what happens if a file changes content? Well.... you will have trees that have the same "names" in the structure of the trees that make up the revisions that you are talking about... but then the IDs will change because the content of the file will change. So, names will be the same, IDs will change. I think you have to use a little bit of `git cat-file -p` starting with your revisions and then the object IDs (trees, blobs) so that you fully understand what's going on.

Comment: Added example to further explain myself.

Comment: @torek's answer has all the gory details, I think. :-)