# Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted

Tags: git

I am a beginner. I try to use git to create the user's name. but when I typed

```
git config --global user.name "XXX"
```

the message shows

> Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted.

I don't know what happened. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293849/fatal-unable-to-read-current-working-directory-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 75):

I had a similar problem after updating to MacOS Catalina 10.15 and updating Xcode Command-line Tools (`xcode-select --install`).

I received the above error when simply trying to do `git status`. Then noticed I couldn't even do `ls`. Apparently it's necessary grant Terminal, or iTerm in my case, "Full Disk Access".

1. Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab
2. Select "Full Disk Access" from the left-side menu
3. Add Terminal and/or iTerm to the app list

See this article for more details: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

**UPDATE - 1/2023:** I recently updated to MacOS Ventura 13.1 and ran into the same issue. Running `xcode-select --install` did the trick for me. Another [helpful article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fix-invalid-active-developer-path-macos-upgrade-1b8afedb690a).

Comment: If you have the same problem with the Git Tower app, add it to the list of Full Disk Access apps as described above.

Comment: Do not forget to re-start your terminal APP.

Answer (score 1):

Check your home directory and `.gitconfig` file permissions using `ls -l` command. If all is ok try to use `sudo chattr -i .gitconfig` to check immutable attribute on this file.

You can find details about this command and file attributes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr).

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in a pretty silly situation. I had a directory open in the terminal, but in Finder, I moved it to another location.

So, I was trying to execute this command in a directory that no longer existed.

I hope this helps someone :)